# Failed to decode downloaded font-- After Bundling in Umbraco Asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I did Bundling of my scripts and Styles yesterday when I upload my website on azure as a dev branch then I am facing Warnings of fonts (Failed to decode downloaded font) [You may see here](http://dev-deal-bargains.azurewebsites.net/). 
In my web.config I had this static content

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".air" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip" />
  <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
  <remove fileExtension=".less" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
  <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <remove fileExtension=".json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

and my one of css file is this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
src:url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');
src:url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an issue of arranging js and css in the bundling file and some path issue. I solved it through